# Upgrade RAM from 20GB (1x 4GB, 1x 16GB) to 32GB (2x 16GB)

Tags: 16.04, ram, swap

I'm currently using Ubuntu 16.04.

When I'm processing large datasets, I sometimes run out of memory.

Therefore, I want to upgrade RAM from 20GB (1x 4GB, 1x 16GB) to 32GB (2x 16GB), can I just swap the 4GB memory stick for the 16GB or will I need to reinstall Ubuntu altogether?

Comment: There would be no need to reinstall the OS for a RAM upgrade.  You do need to check with your motherboard manufacturer if your motherboard will support the RAM that you want to do.  We will not have that answer here for you.

Comment: Thank you, that's been very helpful. Unfortunately, I can't accept the answer as I just opened my account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that was a comment, not an answer, so...

@Terrance "There would be no need to reinstall the OS for a RAM upgrade."

Which is correct...I'll add that it's a good idea to use matched RAM modules. If you can, get the exact 16gig module to what you have installed for best performance and compatibility. If they're not matched or close enough, there's a chance they won't run in dual-channel mode which hinders read/write performance.